# Error trying to update client status in database

Tags: php

I'm trying to send some parameters in the object method, however I'm getting an error that I can not resolve. Note: The error happens before going to the method.

```
<?php 

    if($fatura->getStatus() == 0){
        //log
    }else if($num > 0){


        //id_cliente, id_transacao, status, data_vencimento, data_gerada, valor
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                extract($row);

                //         
                $idCliente = $row['idCliente'];
                $idTransacao = $row['transacao'];
                $data = $row['vencimento'];

                //requisitar o status do cliente
                $status = $fatura->verificarStatus($idTransacao);
                $transacao->atualizarFatura(intval($idCliente), intval($idTransacao), $status, $data);




            } 

    }else{
        //log
    }

?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   atualizarFatura() on string in
>   /srv/http/application/application/financeiro_atualizar.php:50 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /srv/http/application/application/financeiro_atualizar.php on line 50

Comment: I don't think you need the `extract($row);` as you seem to do this yourself - except for `$transacao` which will be a value from the database (most likely a string).  What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: I did not understand your answer.

Comment: Where do you set the var `$transacao`? Could you post the code?

Comment: The object is instantiated at startup.